# pyGTK autosizing notebook tabs

Tags: python, pygtk, autosize, shrink

I am trying to auto-size the tabs in my pygtk gui. Right now I use a for loop to create 
tabs based on USB connections to the computer. This works fine.

If there happens to be more tabs created than can fit into to the window, then I want the tab labels to become smaller, and fit inside, just like browser tabs. I have attached a picture to illustrate the problem.

[image: Factory GUI]

I want those to shrink and fit in the gui window.

Comment: Are you using Gtk+3 or Gtk+2?

Answer (score 1):

```
nb = gtk.Notebook()
nb.set_scrollable(True)
```